# "npm exited with non zero code: 190" when trying to upgrade expo from 37 to 44

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to upgrade the expo SDK from 37 to 45, when I run the "expo upgrade" it tries to install but ends up returning this error message:

"✔ You are currently using SDK 37.0.0. Would you like to update to the latest version, 45.0.0? … yes

✖ Failed to install expo package with error: npm exited with non-zero code: 190
npm exited with non-zero code: 190
Error: npm exited with non-zero code: 190
at ChildProcess.completionListener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
...
at spawnAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
at NpmPackageManager._runAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/src/NodePackageManagers.ts:166:31)
at NpmPackageManager.installAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/src/NodePackageManagers.ts:82:16)
at NpmPackageManager.addWithParametersAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/src/NodePackageManagers.ts:96:18)
at NpmPackageManager.addAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/src/NodePackageManagers.ts:109:5)
at upgradeAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/info/upgradeAsync.ts:496:7)
at actionAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/info/upgradeAsync.ts:42:3)"

my package.json says "cli": "^1.0.1",
"eas": "^0.1.0",
"eas-cli": "^0.22.0",
"expo": "^45.0.0",
"expo-ads-admob": "^8.1.0",
"expo-asset": "~8.1.5",
"expo-cli": "^4.7.3",
"expo-font": "~8.1.0","

I was not able to find any helpful info yet. Please help to upgrade successfully!

Best,
Evan

Comment: Seeing this error myself when upgrading from 44 to 45. No idea the cause.

Comment: Solved it eventually by running `npm install expo@^45.0.0` manually. This still broke, but gave me a more helpful error message, which I was eventually able to track to a bad node_modules directory in a submodule.